# I am trying to maintain an image database folder structure

Tags: c#

I am trying to maintain an image database, so when I add a new image to the particular folder, my program should append old images. Also, I am trying to delete them by using  string[] filePaths with the following code, but it doesn't work...

Can anyone please help me?Simply what i going to do is if the file existing in the root folder(TrainedFaces) or sub-folders(/TrainedFaces/eladena/) avoid it's add previous images again and again....that is the point i stuck in??

e.g:- if i add face1,face2,face3 to the folder (/TrainedFaces/eladena/). after sometime  i create another folder call Linda in side root folder (/TrainedFaces/Linda/) and add face4,face5,in /TrainedFaces/Linda/ sub folder i only need face4,face5 but becoze of this FOR LOOP  it's add face1,face2,face3 as well so 
 in /TrainedFaces/Linda/ have duplicate /TrainedFaces/eladena/ face1,face2,face3. i want to avoid this problem without removing the Loop, if there is Lambda/linq expression to do that?

```
    for (int i = 1; i < trainingImages.ToArray().Length + 1; i++)
    {
        trainingImages.ToArray()[i - 1].Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/eladena/face" + i + ".bmp");
        File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt", labels.ToArray()[i - 1] + "%");
    }
    MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text + "´s face detected and added :)", "Training OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/", "*.bmp");
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
        if (filePath.Contains(".bmp"))
            File.Delete(filePath);
    }
{
    if (filePath.Contains(".bmp"))
        File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

Comment: Have you explored the possibility of using a `FileSystemWatcher` to maintain your in-memory list of images?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Directory.GetFiles` with `searchOption`

Link :http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms143316.aspx

You must add `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to your method `GetFiles`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms143448.aspx

```
 string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"TrainedFaces"), "*.bmp", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: for (int i = 1; i < trainingImages.ToArray().Length + 1; i++)
    {
        trainingImages.ToArray()[i - 1].Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/eladena/face" + i + ".bmp");
        File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt", labels.ToArray()[i - 1] + "%"); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

I think that your requirement of adding unique IDs based on the files that are already uploaded might not scale that well.  As each image is added you will do a full directory scan to find the last image.  This is a lot of wasted I/O operations that will increase as each new image is added.  Instead use an incrementing value in some persistent system (commonly the Primary Key of a database record).  If you are interested in using the smallest number of external systems then take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/) which will dutifully keep track of the last incremented value.

Comment: yes if it's possible when i user database to maintain my image repository, but in this case i use some HDD space to store my crop image to further load them to recognize algorithm purpose.